# Detecting pinch in Android browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, android-browser

So there seems very little around about this. I need to be able to detect pinching in the Android browser with Javascript. Not with use of a plugin (except jQuery). The only site I have seen this implemented is Google Maps.

Lets just say for now I want to be able to pinch inside of a div and it will log when I do so.

Struggling to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Check hammer.js http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/ it looks like `transform` gesture may do what you want.